# Tailwind CSS background image does not work on github pages

Tags: tailwind-css, http-status-code-404, background-image, github-pages

Does anyone know of a github page that was made with just HTML and Tailwind CSS (without any framework, library or static site generator), where a "background image" is displayed, as indicated in the Tailwind documentation [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#customizing-your-theme) or [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#arbitrary-values) ?

I've already used github pages to publish a static page with HTML and CSS files and the images were always displayed, either through the `<img>` tag or through pure CSS with the `background-image` - as you can see here in this [repository](https://github.com/Cristianolm/DisplayImages) and its respective [page](https://cristianolm.github.io/DisplayImages/). However, it seems that with Tailwind CSS, github pages do not recognize background images.

I already have the idea, from some research I did and even from a doubt I posted here, that it has something to do with it the relative path that does not include the name of the repository, since when I am developing the project on my computer I do not take it into account, however I have already tried to modify the path including the name of the repository and the result is always the same (background image is not displayed on github pages).

Does anyone know how to solve this or show a project published on the github pages that was made exclusively with HTML and Tailwind CSS (no React or Jekyll) and that has a background image displayed with Tailwind CSS?

Finally, I leave the link to my [repository](https://github.com/Cristianolm/Tailwind-bgImg) and [github page](https://cristianolm.github.io/Tailwind-bgImg/) where can you see this situation.

Comment: url('img/funk-art-2.png')